# Multiple entry in a month allowed under ESTA?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens, repeat-visits

I am from Australia and planning to visit Canada and U.S this year. I got my ESTA approval but not sure about coming to U.S. twice in a month. I will be visiting NY from Toronto and then back to Toronto and then Vancouver. From there I am planning a trip to LV & LA. Will there be an issue as my second visit will be in a couple of weeks time again to U.S.  Any help please as I am not sure about this, thanks.

Comment: What regulates your entry into the US is the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). ESTA is just a permission to board an aircraft to seek entry. ESTA is valid for multiple flights for a duration of 2 years. The VWP allows you to stay up to 90 days per stay, but be reminded that short trips to neighbouring countries and islands do not reset the clock. However in your case (less than a month) this is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks mate, I appreciate that . Yupp, Australia falls under VWP and ESTA will make sure that I can get to the places , I want to see there. Cheers mate !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not run into any issues. Your reasons for traveling are valid and totally covered under the ESTA program.

I would just take the precaution of bringing along documents that prove your itineraries (your stays in NY, Toronto, Vancouver, LA, and LV) along with a return flight home. This will just show the border guard that you are genuinely traveling and not planning on doing anything illegal during your stay.

Enjoy your trip!